# Azure AD B2C 2 types of expiration date for password depending on the password itself, how to?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have the following scenario:

If a user has a temporary password, that is been set in the last 24 hours, the user is forced to change the password. If the password has been set more than 24 hours ago, then the user is not able to log in.

If a user has a password that has been set in the last 180 days, the user is able to log in. If the password has been set longer than 180 days ago, the user is forced to reset the password.

The two types of password look different, so I can compare the password by a regular expression to check if it is a temporary password or not.

The problem is that knowing that the password is temporary or not, I have to apply the 24 hour or 180 day expiration time of the policy. So how do I know when the password was last updated?

Initially, I have thought in using a custom attribute to store this value, but I thought that this should be recorded somewhere by default. It makes sense to me that Microsoft wanted to audit this on their side for compliance and security purposes. It also makes sense to me that this could probably be on Graph, but so far, I haven't found this filter exists.
Question is, does this filter exist or I need to go through the custom attribute route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results as below:***

To know the when the password of the Azure AD B2C users was last updated, try the below query:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,lastPasswordChangeDateTime
```

[image]

Make sure to consent **`User.Read.All`** permission to fetch the `lastPasswordChangeDateTime`.